# How to theme regions in non-standard themes like Consilium?

Tags: theming

So I'm stuck with a theme that is very difficult to work with because it is nonstandard. It seems like it would like to be Omega and put lots of functionality into the admin UI and out of template files but it seems they forgot to actually add that functionality in there.

So the goal is to add regions and edit existing ones. Normally I would do this in page.tpl.php but this theme does not define region order and html inside a template like this. They've provided a Layout section in their appearance settings but there's no way to actually do anything in this section. No drag, no select, nothing.

So my question is that somewhere in some file, these regions have to be defined in a specific order so where? It's not in page.tpl but it has to be somewhere or else drupal wouldn't know what to do with these regions or how to structure their html.

I know a few suggestions would be to contact the theme maintainer but they are horrible on support. Another suggestion might be to choose another theme but my company picked this one and so I have no choice. I also have a Friday deadline and just got to start this week so figuring out this silly theme has been taking up all my time.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

regions are normally defined in the [theme_name].info file in the theme directory. Here is an example from the Bartik theme:

> name = Bartik
>
> description = A flexible, recolorable theme with many regions.
>
> package = Core
>
> version = VERSION
>
> core = 7.x
>
> stylesheets[all][] = css/layout.css
>
> stylesheets[all][] = css/style.css
>
> stylesheets[all][] = css/colors.css
>
> stylesheets[print][] = css/print.css
>
> regions[header] = Header
>
> regions[help] = Help
>
> regions[page_top] = Page top
>
> regions[page_bottom] = Page bottom
>
> regions[highlighted] = Highlighted

Comment: Yes I know. What I'm referring to is normally in page.tpl you'd have print $header or print $content and things like that. This theme does not have any of that.

Comment: well in your question you ask where they are defined - and they are defined in the info file. If they are not being rendered or printed in the page.tpl.php file, I would check the template.php for overrides that could be accomplishing it possibly using theme settings...

Comment: "these regions have to be defined in a specific order so where" clearly I'm specifying the order they are in the template and discuss at length what I'm asking. Thanks for the answer, but I'm just letting you know it has no bearing at all on what I'm asking and I think you jumped the gun thinking you knew what I was asking before reading it fully. Thanks again.

Comment: no I think I answered as per the question - it's not my fault that the question is worded poorly. a hook in template.php can cause a variable to be assigned and then printed in page.tpl.php (a variable that doesn't necessarily match a naming convention you might recognize) rendering the regions in any given order as defined by the hook or function

Comment: you could also take a look at html.tpl.php if it exists - perhaps they are bypassing page.tpl.php entirely for some reason